# How to deal with errors so they show up in the google play developer console?

Tags: android, logging, exception, google-play

I am volunteering for an organization building an Android app. We are going to publish a BETA version on google play soon, And there is a section in the google play developer console interface called **"Crashes and ANRs"** that I am hoping we can use for finding errors in the app

Now for the question:

How can we write the exception handling code inside the app so that it works well together with this section in the google developer console? (Any other useful tips in this context is very welcome, we are looking to find errors using this interface)

For example, is it a good approach to use the `Log.d(tag, msg, throwable)` method? (Please note the throwable at the end).

Can we benefit from a custom exception class or classes?

Kind Regards, Tord

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the Crashes and ANRs in the Play Developer Console is that they only show up if the user decides to report them. If you want to get crash reports ANY time that your application crashes, there are a few libraries you can use.

[ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) and [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) are two that I would recommend taking a look at. Both are used by a large number of apps on the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of how a crash log may look like if you turn on Proguard in the "Crashes and ANRs".

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList angel.twitch.contactnumberformatter.app.b.b.b()' on a null object reference
at angel.twitch.contactnumberformatter.app.a.a.h.a(Unknown Source)
at angel.twitch.contactnumberformatter.app.a.h.a(Unknown Source)
at angel.twitch.contactnumberformatter.app.a.h.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
```

that's all you are going to have to work with for the crash. 
Also notice that some of the codes are obfuscated? (the a.a.h.a part of "angel.twitch.contactnumberformatter.app.a.a.h.a")

you will need to look at the proguard mapping file (mapping.txt) to look for the corresponding methods. then trace your way up from there.

mapping.txt can be found in the build output folder (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

and yes, you can do a throw and set the exception message. you need to remind your beta testers to submit the crash report though. just remember to remove those codes in production (you don't want your production app to crash).